# cross-tabulated queries with an IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am curious if any one can give me a hand.

**This is the table and the fields:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfUTa.jpg)

**This is the example I got:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dpli.jpg)

**And this is what I have so far**

```
Select ipno,
SUM(IF(retcode<100,0)) As '<100',
SUM(IF(retcode>=100   and retcode<200,0)) As '100s',
SUM(IF(retcode>=200  and retcode<300,0)) As '200s',
SUM(IF(retcode>=300 and retcode<400,0)) As '300s',
SUM(IF(retcode>=400,0)) As '400s'
From WebLog
Group By ipno;
```

**But I'm keep getting this error**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) As '<100',
SUM(IF(retcode>=100   and retcode<200,0)) As '100s',
SUM(IF(retcod' at line 2
```

Comment: The MySQL `IF()` function takes *three* arguments. Sample code is invalid because only two arguments are provided to `IF()` function. (Maybe the intent was to use `IFNULL()` function, to translated a NULL value to a zero.)

Comment: @spencer7593, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `if()` in MySQL:

```
Select ipno,
       SUM(retcode < 100) As `<100`,
       SUM(retcode >= 100 and retcode < 200) As `100s`,
       SUM(retcode >= 200 and retcode < 300) As `200s`,
       SUM(retcode >= 300 and retcode < 400) As `300s`,
       SUM(retcode >= 400) As `400s`
From WebLog
Group By ipno;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true an d"0" for false.

In addition, don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for date and string constants.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also go it to work with the IF() statement.

Answer (score 0):

**This also worked for me. Thanks everyone.**

```
Select ipno,
SUM(IF(retcode<100,1,0)) As '<100',
SUM(IF(retcode>=100   and retcode<200,1,0)) As '100s',
SUM(IF(retcode>=200  and retcode<300,1,0)) As '200s',
SUM(IF(retcode>=300 and retcode<400,1,0)) As '300s',
SUM(IF(retcode>=400,1,0)) As '400s'
From WebLog
Group By ipno;
```